# React.js button class not changing

Tags: css, reactjs, rxjs

I have a checkbox and want to change the class of the button:

```
   let able = 'btn btn-secondary" disabled';
   
    function handleChange(e) {
     let isChecked = e.target.checked;
     if (isChecked===true){
         able = '"btn btn-primary"';
        console.log(able);
  }
```

console logs **"btn btn-primary"** which is correct , however the button is not changing at all
and in the return:

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
  <button type='submit' class={able}>Register</button>
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React.js you should use state. I suggest you learn about the basics of React. For your case, this should do the trick:

**JSX**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
   
const handleChange = (e) => {
     setChecked(e.target.checked);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
<button type='submit' disabled={!isChecked} class={`btn btn-${isChecked ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}`}>Register</button>
```